# How to get only git revisions that are branch heads?

Tags: git, branch, git-log

Given a history such as

```
commit         | ref
---------------+------------------------------
3ad2c1         | master
b34b14         |
afeg41         | origin/merge-requests/421
1fea34         |
6422bc         |
15fcda         | origin/merge-requests/152
```

How can I can get a list of only the named refs, i.e. `master, origin/merge-requests/{421,152}` between two given commits?

Comment: The question is odd. If you want a list of refs, why not use `git for-each-ref`? Because even if it's not the answer to your question in the body of your post, `git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname:short)' refs/heads` *will* output the commit hashes of your named refs, which answers at least technically the question in the title. What's the purpose of this list?

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks, `for-each-ref` works indeed. The purpose of this list is in my specific case that I want `git bisect` to only search merge requests (from GitLab, fast-forward merged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the origin part, you could use [`git for-each-ref` with a pattern](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-ltpatterngt82308203)

```
 git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname:short)' refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*
```

That would limit to the merge-requests branches.